Range of a positive operator as invariant subspace for an invertible operator.
Does there exist an invertible operator T and a positive operator P (with Range(P) not closed) such that Range(TP) is a proper subspace of Range(P)?
Thanks in advance.

Yes. For example, on $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, let $T$ be the rightward bilateral shift (i.e., $T(e_n) = e_{n+1}$ for all $n$). Let $P$ be the diagonal operator defined by,
$$P(e_n) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n}e_n, &n \geq 1\\
0, &n \leq 0
\end{cases}$$
Then $P$ is positive with non-closed range and $\text{range}(TP) \subsetneq \text{range}(P)$.

Thanks a lot. What if Range(P) is closed? i.e, Can an invertible operator T take a closed subspace M properly into M?

If we take $M= \overline{range(P)}$ in the above example, then $T(M) \subsetneq M$. Am I right?

@AnandOR That is correct, yes, so $P$ being the projection onto $M$ would be an example to the case where $\text{range}(P)$ is closed.
